# What happened to the alien pod that Ben found the Omnitrix in?

Tags: ben-10

In the beginning of Ben 10, Ben gets the Omnitrix from an alien pod he found in the woods. What happens to the pod after that?

Comment: either it got buried or government/Plumbers got to it and hid it

Comment: I thought it self-destructed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the premiere episode of Ben 10, "And Then There Were 10" the life-support pod that delivered the [Omnitrix](http://ben10.wikia.com/wiki/Prototype_Omnitrix) was likely non-functional after its crash-landing on Earth.

- The pod was destroyed by Vilgax's agent halfway through the episode before Max could find it at the crash site.

[image: Omnitrix delivery pod destroyed]

*Omnitrix delivery pod destroyed*

- Despite the fact that [Grandpa Max Tennyson](http://ben10.wikia.com/wiki/Max_Tennyson) was on vacation, if it hadn't been destroyed  it would have likely been recovered and hidden by the [Plumbers](http://ben10.wikia.com/wiki/Plumbers).